# obtener textbox de ventana modal en otra nueva

Tags: jquery, html, html5, bootstrap

alguien sabe como obtener el valor de una caja de texto de una ventana modal en otra nueva ventana modal?

tengo una ventana modal que tiene dos botones, tambien tengo un valor clave en un textbox que necesito recuperar en otra ventana modal para procesar ese valor, trataba de pasar el valor en el evento clic de un boton con el siguiente codigo

```js
$("#btnno").click(function () {
  $('#modalPregunta').modal('hide');
  $('#modalNo').modal('show',$("#valor").val());
});
```

y lo recuperaba asi

```js
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (evnt) {

  var btn = $(evnt.relatedTarget);  
  console.log( btn);
});
```

pero al debuguearlo no me obtiene ningun valor

Comment: Hola @Drago25, no entiendo la segunda parte de tu código. Lo que hacés ahí es escribir en consola el elemento sobre el cual se hizo click para abrir el popup. Tengo una pregunta, cuando abrís el segundo modal, el elemento que contiene el valor que necesitás: sigue existiendo?

Comment: @ibooio cuando hago debug con Google chrome tiene una parte llamada consola donde imprime con console.log lo que tiene la variable btn, lo uso para fines prácticos, el valor que necesito lo contiene la primer ventana modal y no existe en la segunda es por eso que revisando un poco en internet veia que se podía pasar una variable de esta forma  "$('#modalNo').modal('show',$("#valor").val())" pero no lo he podido recuperar, no se si sea correcto

Comment: En el evento show.bs.modal agregá console.log($("#valor").val()); (Asegurate de que el textbox tiene id igual a 'valor'). Y fijate si escribe en la consola el valor que contiene el textbox en cuestión

Comment: Amigo @ibooio si lo recupere con solo $("#valor").val() y sin pasar valor alguno cuando muestro la ventana modal con  $('#modalNo').modal('show',$("#valor").val()), gracias de nuevo saludos tenia varias horas sin poder hacer eso =)

Comment: Eso es porque el elemento sigue existiendo, aunque no esté visible. Saludos. Cierra la pregunta con la solución :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente puedes obtener el valor de la primer ventana modal utilizando JQuery o JavaScript. Con JQuery se usa `$('#elementoID').val();` esto obtiene el valor del elemento con el ID "elementoID", dado que las ventanas modales no pierden sus valores al cerrase el valor seguirá presente en el elemento aunque esté oculta, otra alternativa puede ser almacenar el valor que requieres de la primer ventana modal en una variable global en caso de ser requerida y más adelante en tu código solamente usas el valor de esa variable.

Answer (score 1):

la solución al problema fue recuperar el valor solo con $("#valor").val() que es el textbox de mi primera ventana modal, sin pasar valor alguno en el evento clic $('#modalNo').modal('show',$("#valor").val());

Comment: acepta una respuesta si ya lo resolviste. Puede ser la tuya :)